# What are RSEQs (Restartable Sequences) and how to use them?

Tags: c++, linux, optimization, system-calls, restartable-sequence

Linux 4.18 introduced the [`rseq(2)`](https://kib.kiev.ua/kib/rseq.pdf) syscall. I found only one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63433790/12501684) on SO that mentions `rseq` at all, and there is relatively little information about it online, so I decided to ask. **What are *restartable sequences* and how can they be used by programmers?**

I had to search for [`restartable sequences: fast user-space percpu critical sections`](https://www.google.com/search?q=restartable+sequences%3A+fast+user-space+percpu+critical+sections) to get any meaningful results. I was able to find the [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d7822b1e24f2df5df98c76f0e94a5416349ff759) that added the relevant functionality to the kernel. Further research lead me to the [2013 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIpE2pKA9Wk) that I believe to be the first introduction of the concept. Much work has been done by a team working at a company called EfficiOS. They describe what are [their intentions](https://www.efficios.com/blog/2019/02/08/linux-restartable-sequences/) behind contributing this feature to the Linux kernel.

It looks like this feature is very little known, but apparently it is used to [optimize performance](https://google.github.io/tcmalloc/rseq.html) in the TCMalloc allocator. Generally, it seems that it is some kind of [concurrency optimization](https://mcyoung.xyz/2023/03/29/rseq-checkout/).

Although the listed sources provide background information there is yet to be an explanation of RSEQs provided on SO. It would be useful to hear where else and how are they used in practice.

##### Edit: Practical example

Suppose [I am creating a C++ job system](https://github.com/janekb04/job_system). A part of it is a lock-free [multi-producer single-consumer queue](https://github.com/janekb04/job_system/blob/main/src/mpsc_list.h). How could I introduce the use of the `rseq(2)` syscall into my code to potentially improve its performance?

```cpp
class mpsc_list_node
{
    mpsc_list_node* _next;

    template<typename T>
        requires std::derived_from<T, mpsc_list_node>
    friend class mpsc_list;
};

template<typename T>
    requires std::derived_from<T, mpsc_list_node>
class mpsc_list
{
private:
    std::atomic<T*> head{ nullptr };

private:
    static constexpr size_t COMPLETED_SENTINEL = 42;

public:
    mpsc_list() noexcept = default;
    mpsc_list(mpsc_list&& other) noexcept :
        head{ other.head.exchange(reinterpret_cast<T*>(COMPLETED_SENTINEL), std::memory_order_relaxed) }
    {
    }

    bool try_enqueue(T& to_append)
    {
        T* old_head = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        do
        {
            if (reinterpret_cast<size_t>(old_head) == COMPLETED_SENTINEL)
                [[unlikely]]
                {
                    return false;
                }
            to_append._next = old_head;
        } while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, &to_append, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
        return true;
    }

    template<typename Func>
    void complete_and_iterate(Func&& func) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<Func, T&>)
    {
        T* p = head.exchange(reinterpret_cast<T*>(COMPLETED_SENTINEL), std::memory_order_acquire);
        while (p)
            [[likely]]
            {
                T* cur  = p;
                T* next = static_cast<T*>(p->_next);
                p       = next;
                func(*cur);
            }
    }
};
```

The purpose of this `mpsc_list` and its place in the job system is well explained by my [`README`](https://github.com/janekb04/job_system/tree/main):

> #### Inter-job synchronization
>
> The only synchronization primitive used is an atomic counter. This idea stems from the
> famous [GDC talk](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1022187/Parallelizing-the-Naughty-Dog-Engine)
> on the implementation of a job system using fibers in the Naughty Dog's game engine.
>
> The common promise type of the jobs (`promise_base`) is actually a derived type from
> `mpsc_list`, a multi-producer single-consumer list. This list stores the jobs dependent
> on the current job. It is a lock-less linked list implemented using atomic operations.
> Each node stores a pointer to the dependent's promise and the next node. Interestingly,
> this linked list does not use any dynamic memory allocation.
>
> When a job `co_await`s a (possibly 1-sized) set of dependency jobs, it does a few things.
> Firstly, its promise sets its own internal atomic counter to the number of dependency jobs.
> Then, it allocates (on the stack) a dependency-count-sized array of `notifier` objects. The `notifier` type
> is the type of the linked list's node. The created `notifier`s all point to the job
> being suspended. They do not have a next node.
>
> Then, the job goes through each of its dependency jobs and tries to append the corresponding
> `notifier` to the dependency's list. If that dependency has already completed, this operation
> fails. This is because when a job returns, it sets its list's head to a special sentinel value.
> If the dependency has already completed (for example, on a different thread), then the
> suspending job simply decrements its own atomic counter. If the dependency hasn't completed yet, it appends the `notifier` to that dependency's list.
> It does so using a [CAS loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).
>
> After having gone through each of the dependencies, the suspending job checks how many
> of its dependencies have already completed. If all of them have, then it doesn't suspend
> and immediately continues execution. This isn't just an optimization. This is necessary
> for the job system to function properly. This is because this job system *does not* have
> a *suspended job* queue. The job system only has a *ready job* queue. Suspended jobs are
> stored only inside their dependencies' linked lists. Hence, if a job would suspend, while
> not having any dependencies, it would never get resumed.
>
> When a job returns, it traverses its linked list of dependents. Firstly, it sets the list's
> head to the special sentinel value. Then, it goes through all of the jobs, atomically
> decrementing their atomic counters. The decrement is a [RMW operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93modify%E2%80%93write), so the job reads the counter's previous value. If it is one,
> then it knows that it is the last dependency to complete for that job, and it `push`es it
> to the job queue.

Answer (score 1):

The `rseq` syscall was introduced to allow for `restartable sequences`, which were invented to allow for `per-cpu variables` in userspace. Per-cpu variables are easy in kernel-space as you can disable preemption at any time you reference a per-cpu.

In userspace you have to account for unwanted preemption if you want to handle your per-cpu variables consistently with respect to the current thread/CPU. For that the `restartable sequences` mechanism was introduced